# jhipster 4: how customize JHipsterProperties?

Tags: java, jhipster

With jhipster 4.0.2 how customize JHipsterProperties?

The class is now in a jhipster jar, and with the annotation @ConfigurationProperties, and is used by many classes in the jhipster jar.

I don't see in this context how to customize it beside by copying all jhipser jar and use the duplicated classes.

I know I can use my own separated configurations, this isn't my question.

Comment: Your are not supposed to add/remove properties under the jhipster prefix, please clarify your use case.

Comment: For example, I want that  ignoreUnknownFields = true to be sure there's no spelling mistake. Or I want clean the properties class to be sure another developper or a future developper doesn't get confused by some unused setting.